# webserver with sophos utm - website not found 404 error

Tags: networking, webserver, iis, sophos

I am trying to host a website through Sophos UTM and setting up a DMZ
I configured the website in IIS and configured the webserver in Sophos UTM
did the port forwarding in the router tested it on the server and it worked
when I test the website I get not found 404 error this is with a NOIP hostname
when I test it with the public IP address I get forbidden error
no problem with the IIS configuration I tested it without going through Sophos UTM and it works
this is the [guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-protect-your-web-server-with-sophos-utm#setup-the-dmz) I followed in configuring the webserver in Sophos UTM

Comment: this is some pictures for my [configuration](https://imgur.com/a/NH2GQvI)

Comment: It worked but not exactly the way I want it to, the only way for it to work is to remove the hostname from the IIS bindings and the virtual server and use my public IP address instead, also now I'm getting a 400 error - bad request this happened after I changed in the IIS bindings IP address settings from a static address 192.168.5.5 to All Unassigned, this persists even though I changed it back to 192.168.5.5, I'm thinking maybe there is something wrong with my DNS configuration here is [pictures](https://imgur.com/a/wGOSuXQ) of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution that worked for me in case, someone faces a similar problem in the future
I simply was missing a [DNAT rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVAlY.jpg) the website become accessible as soon as I added it

the credit of this solution is to briain from the Sophos community